# Finding the cube root of negative number within a custom function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

I'm trying to write a program that shows the gradients on either side of a stationary point. But for functions like x^(4/3) with stationary point at x=0, the derivative has the term x^(1/3), and (-0.001)^(1/3) is giving a complex number.

I've read other answers saying that Mathematica uses a complex root as the default principal root, and that recommend using Surd instead, but I don't think I can use that if the function is a user input. Is there any other way to restrict it to the real value instead of a complex one?

```
  gsign[f_] := Module[{dy, xsp, sn},
  dy := D[f, x];
  xsp := NSolve[dy == 0, x, Reals];
  Print[xsp];
  sn := Length[xsp];
  Do[
   xlsp := dy /. x -> (xsp[[i, 1, 2]] - 0.001);
   xrsp := dy /. x -> (xsp[[i, 1, 2]] + 0.001);
   Print[xlsp, ",", xrsp];
   , {i, sn}
   ]
  ]
```

Any additional advice on improving the code would be welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try and see if this does what you want.

```
gsign[f_, x_] := Module[{dy, xsp, sn, n, m, any},
  dy = D[f, x];
  dy = dy /. any_.*Power[x, Rational[m_, n_]] :> any*Surd[x^m, n];
  xsp = NSolve[dy == 0, x, Reals];
  Print[xsp];
  sn = Length[xsp];
  Do[
   xlsp = dy /. x -> (xsp[[i, 1, 2]] - 0.001);
   xrsp = dy /. x -> (xsp[[i, 1, 2]] + 0.001);
   Print[xlsp, ",", xrsp]
   ,
   {i, sn}]
  ]
```

Now

```
gsign[x^(4/3), x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Yes, this worked, thank you. If I understand it right, the added line looks for something of the form x^(m/n) and rewrites it using Surd?

Comment: @PHPuzzler yes, that is correct.